# Approval Workflow in Document Library

Tags: workflow, document, library, approval

Is it possible to do the following in SharePoint online?

1. Upload a document to a document library
2. Send this document for approval to a specific person (to approver)
3. The approver to approve or reject the document

I appreciate if you could provide some details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to Add approval workflow on the document library as OOTB as mentioned below:

- Open your document library.
- From the above ribbon > Click on Workflow Settings > Add a workflow.

[image]

- Add approval Workflow and configure it based on your requirements as mentioned at  [All about Approval workflows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

[image]

**Note:** By default, the Approval workflow is not activated and is not listed in the Select a workflow template list box of the association form. To make it available for use, a site administrator must activate them at the site collection level.

For more details to apply your above points check [All about Approval workflows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can attach Approval Workflow to the Document Library which is an out of the box workflow.

- Go to Library Settings.
- Workflow settings
- Add a Workflow
- Select "Approval Workflow" from the list of available workflows
- Choose Name and when to raise workflow
- Click "Next" it will ask for the approver details.
- Click "Ok" to attach and satart running for new items.